# Testing GraphQL resolvers with Jest

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, graphql, jestjs

I'm looking to write tests for a GraphQL resolver using Jest and really don't know where to start. The resolvers are simple CRUD functions to write to a MongoDB database using mongoose on NodeJS.

Type:

```
type Article {
  _id: ID!
  title: String
  authors: [User]
}
```

Query

```
extend type Query {
  articles: [Article]
  article(_id: ID!): Article
}
```

Resolvers (Read only)

```
Query: {
  articles: () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Article.find({}, (err, articles) => {
      if (err) reject(err);
      else resolve(articles);
    });
  }),
  article: (root, {
    _id,
  }) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Article.findById(_id, (err, article) => {
      if (err) reject(err);
      else resolve(article);
    });
  }),
},
```

How do I test without having to interact with the database?

Comment: Especially with MongoDB there are so many resources out there.
https://medium.com/entria/testing-a-graphql-server-using-jest-4e00d0e4980e
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongo-mock
https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/mongodb.html

Comment: As far as I can see that will create a mock server where I can test mongodb commands, but not with testing the graphQL resolvers. If I import the resolvers file into the test it will connect to the "real" database.

It seems I would need to intercept that connection and replace with a mock db

Answer (score 0):

follow these steps

- Use environment variable to change database according to mode(production,testing,development)
- import schema
- write tests and use graphql like this

  ```
  const query=`mutation name($id:String!)  //dummy example query
     {
          user(id:$id)
          {
           //fields goes here
            }
     }` 
  const result = await graphql(schema, query, {}, {}, data);
  if (result.data) {
      return result.data.addEventTag
  } else {
      throw new Error(...result.errors.map(err => ` \n${err.message}`));
  }
  ```

so there is no need to import resolver directly, graphQl will use it, make sure to connect to database according to mode.